# Recurrence relation: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log(n)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I have a recurrence relation which is like the following:

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log<sub>2</sub> n

I am using recursion tree method to solve this. And at the end, i came up with the following equation:

T(n)=(2log<sub>2</sub>n)(n-1)-(1*2 + 2*2<sup>2</sup> + ... + k*2<sup>k</sup>) where k=log<sub>2</sub>n.

I am trying to find a theta notation for this equation. But i cannot find a closed formula for the sum (1*2 + 2*2<sup>2</sup> + ... + k*2<sup>k</sup>). How can i find a big theta notation for T(n)?

Comment: Should probably be on http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 1*2 + 2*2^2 + ... + k*2^k = 2((k-1) 2^k + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These recurrence can be solved with a [masters theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). In your case `a = 2`, `b = 2` and therefore `c = logb(a) = 1`.

Your `f(n) = log n` and because `n^c` grows faster than your `f`, it dominates the solution and you fall in the first case. So the complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know some calculus you should be able to solve that easily.

1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^(n+1) = (x^(n+2) - 1) / (x - 1)

Multiplying by x,
x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^(n + 2) = (x^(n + 3) - x) / (x - 1)

Differentiating the LHS will give you your series for x = 2. Differentiating the RHS will give you the closed form.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to compute your complexity, it will be much easier.

Comment: Thank you, but my homework question explicitly wants me to use recursion tree method

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are doing some mistake, as per my calculations:

> T(n)=(k-1)*log(n/(2^(k-1)))+2^k*T(n/2^k).

Put k=log(n)

I can post an image of my solution if you like. :)